# Pandas : make new column after nth row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following table as a data frame.

```
0
8
990
15
70
85
36
2
43
5
68
61
62
624
65
82
523
98
```

I want to create a new column after every third row. So the data should look like this.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't look like a new column after every 3rd row now that you changed your desired output... sure you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your column can be converted into an array(i.e., list). If this is the case, you can break down the value by array and create an array of array. Then, use the array of array to create a dataframe.

The code might look something like this:

```py
listofitems = [...]
## create new dataframe based on list index jump
newdf = pd.DataFrame([listofitems[i::3] for i in range(3)])
## transpose dataframe to 3 columns dataframe
newdf = newdf.T
```

For the example given above, 4139055 rows is not a big data. If you do have a big and complex data, please take a look at PySpark specifically on dataframe with Sparks. This is one of the big data frameworks that help optimizing data transformation over big dataframe.

Comment: Oh no the data is big for me :)

Comment: @RakeshMulik check out this documentation and see if this help: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

numbers= [0,
8,
990,
15,
70,
85,
36,
2,
43,
5,
68,
61,
62,
624,
65,
82,
523,
98]

pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(numbers, (6,3)))
```

Comment: Shape of passed values is (4841, 855), indices imply (4139055, 1) having this error

Comment: My data base is big having 4139055 rows and i am trying to slice into 855 pcs of subset

Comment: @RakeshMulik show your code

Comment: Thanks was able to solve it with some tweaking